# A elementary Lisp procedure error

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

```
(define (sum-two-sqrt a b c)

    (cond ((and (<= c a) (<= c b)) sqrt-sum(a b))
           ((and (<= a b) (<= a c)) sqrt-sum(b c))
           ((and (<= b a) (<= b c)) sqrt-sum(a c))
    )
)
(define (sqrt-sum x y)
           (+ (* x x) (*y y))
)
(define (<= x y)
      (not (> x y))

(sum-two-sqrt 3 4 5)
```

This is my code

Please help me to fix the problem. :)

I just start studing Lisp today.

learned some C before but the two language is QUITE DIFFERENT!

This is the question
Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers.

If you have better algorithm

POST IT!

Thank you :)

Comment: `(sqrt-sum a b)` not `sqrt-sum(a b)`, also why define `<=` ? isn't it already defined?

Comment: OK, I changed the sqrt-sum(a b) to (sqrt-sum a b). The procedure could run now, but the result is not right.

Comment: Please post your solution for others' benefit.

Comment: Next time, _describe_ your problem.  You omitted describing why you think there are problems.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to define `<=`, it's a primitive operation. After fixing a couple of typos:

- `sqrt-sum`: you were incorrectly invoking the procedure; the opening parenthesis must be written *before* the procedure name, not *after*.
- `sqrt-sum`: `(*y y)` is incorrect, you surely meant `(* y y)`; the space(s) after an operator matter.

This should work:

```
(define (sqrt-sum x y)
  (+ (* x x) (* y y)))

(define (sum-two-sqrt a b c)
  (cond ((and (<= c a) (<= c b)) (sqrt-sum a b))
        ((and (<= a b) (<= a c)) (sqrt-sum b c))
        ((and (<= b a) (<= b c)) (sqrt-sum a c))))
```

Or another alternative:

```
(define (sum-two-sqrt a b c)
  (let ((m (min a b c)))
    (cond ((= a m) (sqrt-sum b c))
          ((= b m) (sqrt-sum a c))
          (else (sqrt-sum a b)))))
```

Comment: Your second solution is rather elegant, using three arguments to <=

Comment: in python i'd do something like args.remove(min(args)) to pull the smallest arg out of the list, then return sum(arg **2 for arg in args). i would think a lisp translation of that would be even more elegant perhaps?

Comment: I don't know python, but that looks good. If you would want to do it functionally, you could make a list of the arguments, sort them in descending order, take the first two elements, map these to their squares, sum the resulting list of two items to produce your result.

Comment: Come on guys, removing elements? sorting? mapping? that's overkill! my second solution is as simple as it can get for a fixed number of parameters

Comment: yah yah, you have a point for this toy exercise but part of the reason they teach lisp in school is to understand those concepts, right? and be fair, my solution is 2 short lines of code plus a check that the number of args passed in is 3, not exactly bloat.

Comment: No, I disagree: I think that for an experienced programmer, remove the smallest and square the others is a reasonable way to say it. See my answer below for the code (I had to make it an "answer" so that I could format the code).

Comment: P.S.: it goes without saying that this my code would be a terrible solution to an introductory programming assignment, as it depends on having a solid understanding of lots of fiddly bits.

Comment: Oops, gave credit solely to River rather than you. Edited now.

Comment: list and sort, remove... alittle much for a simple exercize isn't it? how about just summing all three squares and subtracting the minimum? or better yet, Óscar's answer?

Comment: Your "simpler" version is wrong, sorry. `(<= a b c)` means `(and (<= a b) (<= b c))`, not `(and (<= a b) (<= a c))`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young ouch. you're right. I replaced it with a not-as-simple but correct version.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on a suggestion by @J.Spiral and seconded by @River, the following Racket code reads nicely to me:

```
#lang racket

(define (squares-of-larger l)
  (define two-larger (remove (apply min l) l))
  (for/sum ([i two-larger]) (* i i)))

(squares-of-larger '(3 1 4)) ;; should be 25
```

Please note that this solution is entirely functional, since "remove" just returns a new list.

Also note that this isn't even in the same neighborhood with HtDP; I just wanted to express this concisely, and show off for/sum.

Answer (score 0):

the algorithm seems to work, just turn

```
*y
```

to

```
* y
```

whitespace is important here, else you're telling the interpreter you want to usethe function `*y`

add a close paren after

```
(define (<= x y) (not (> x y))

sqrt-sum(a b)
```

turns to

```
(sqrt-sum a b)
```

and ditto for the other sqrt-sum calls

**edit:** also a possibility:

```
(define (square a) (* a a))
(define (square-sum a b c)
    (- (+ (square a) 
          (square b)
          (square c))
       (square (min a b c))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have Scheme interpreter here, but below seems to be shorter then other suggestions :) So it's in CL, but should look very similar in Scheme.

```
(defun sum-two-sqrt (a b c)
  (let ((a (max a b))
        (b (max (min a b) c)))
    (+ (* a a) (* b b))))
```

In Scheme this would translate to:

```
(define (sum-two-sqrt a b c)
  (let ((a (max a b))
        (b (max (min a b) c)))
    (+ (* a a) (* b b))))
```